# 04 Pontiac grand Prix fail

Tags: pontiac, overheating, alarm, grand-prix

So I bought my car, 2004 Pontiac Grand Prix and 30 minute it started to over heat.

The dealership had no water or transmission fluid so I put both. All of a sudden I turn the car to start makes a screeching noise but I turn it off it stays on. OK, so I drive home. Alarm start going off and locks going crazy. Now it won't start at all please help me.

The battery is good but it just won't start.

***What could be the problem?***

Comment: Tow it back to the dealership and get your money back. They didn't even bother to put some coolant or transmission fluid in before selling the car.

Comment: I have to agree, it sounds as though your best bet is to take it back and get a different car.  This one sounds like it may have any number of problems.

Comment: I don't know how much I would trust a dealership that doesn't top off basic engine fluids before trying to sell a car.